# Conditional \endinput

Tags: conditionals, luatex, programming, cyrillic

I want to prevent processing rest part of a package in case if it is loaded not from lualatex. For some reason I cannot load ifluatex package, so I borrowed definition of `\ifluatex` from that package and invented the following chunk of code:

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname luatexversion\endcsname\relax % = not \inluatex
  %\typeout{^^J********************** not LuaTeX^^J}
  \PackageError{babel}{
    ^^J\space\space * Option russianu is intended for LuaTeX only.         
    ^^J\space\space * Option russian  is used instead.                  
  }
  \relax
  \input{russianb.ldf}  
  \let\@next@action\endinput
\else
  %\typein{^^J********************** LuaTeX^^J}
  \let\@next@action\relax
\fi
\@next@action
```

It seemed to work but **Is there a better solution**. In particular, it is desirable to avoid introduction of `\@next@action` because it is used the only time.

Just to explain: my goal is to hack babel with option russian to make it working painlessly with LuaLaTeX without any additional hacks (as described, eg, in [\tableofcontents encoding issue with lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/tableofcontents-encoding-issue-with-lualatex) and [LuaTeX cyrillic hyphenation problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5717/luatex-cyrillic-hyphenation-problems))

Comment: What's the problem with package `ifluatex`?

Comment: @Marco: It is not problem of `ifluatex`. LaTeX prohibits using `\RequirePackage` before processing options in `babel.sty`. I got error if I put `\RequirePackagein` at any place of `russian.ldf` to be read by `babel.sty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is the last action before the end of the conditional, you can just use

```
  ...
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
```

which will end the conditional then end input of the current file.

Comment: Of course, this is not anything to do with the particular case: it's a general point.

Comment: @Patrick While true, I'd say it's 'bad style' (code layout and logic both compromised).

Comment: Yes, I agree, and before I saw your comment, I have removed mine.

Answer (score 5):

```
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \PackageWarning{babel}{%
    Option `russianu' is intended for LuaTeX only.\MessageBreak
    Option `russian' will be used instead.}
  \input{russianb.ldf}
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
```

If you don't want to load **ifluatex** (but I don't see why), the test can be

```
\ifdefined\luatexversion
```

I wouldn't use `\PackageError`, since you're providing the correct way out.

Note: the `\expandafter` before `\endinput` is not necessary, provided one puts the `\fi` on the same line as `\endinput`

```
\if...
  ...
\endinput\fi
```

because TeX will read till the end of the line anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, but \RequirePackage{ifluatex} cannot be used inside babel's .ldf files. See my reply to @Marko's comment.

Comment: Then `\ifdefined\luatexversion` should do. Oberdiek uses an indirect way because he wants his packages not to depend on e-TeX features beyond necessity. But yours is aimed to users of recent TeX distributions in which `latex` and `pdflatex` know them for certain.